# how to set imageview.setvisibility(view.gone) in on item click in listiew

Tags: android, listview

I have project that show categorybooks in listview when I click in one row in listview ,

differentbook from it opens .and show the imageview next  each book.but can give me code that do this. i have sample adapter and notifyDataSetChanged dos'nt work.can tell me code that imageview.setvisibility(view.gone) when click each row of list.
**give me code please**

the  piece of important code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Category.this,
                        categoryList, R.layout.category_item,
                        new String[] { TAG_CATEGORY_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.category_name});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {



                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        switch (arg2) {
                        case 0:

                            intent.setClass(arg1.getContext(),
                                    Computer.class);


                            break;
                        case 1:
                            intent.setClass(arg1.getContext(),
                                    Management.class);
                            break;
                        case 2:intent.setClass(arg1.getContext(),
                                Literature.class);
                        break;
                        case 3:intent.setClass(arg1.getContext(),
                                Health.class);
                        break;
```

Comment: you have to put some effort on your project , then if you have a problem here is lots of nice people which will help you , without showing any effort no body give you codes!

Comment: I could not understand your question,please explain more,I will help you if it is possible.

Comment: @Arash I have effort I put in onitemclick imageview.setvisility(view.gone). but has error.i want to use   notifyDataSetChanged  but dos'nt work.please help

Comment: @MHP my project about bookstore.after a person click in forexample computerbooks the shopping icons near books show.

Comment: @nasim : notifyDataSetChanged() will work whenever your adapter data has been changed not for changing any view. if you want hide your ImageView which is inside a ListView , you can set an OnclickListener for your row Inside if Adapter getView() function . then after clicking you can set Visibility of your ImageView Gone.

Comment: @nasim : also for having a complete control over your adapter use custom adapter class to access it's CallBack functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question asked in general and I can help you currectly but I provide you one custom adapter that maybe help you:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            CustomListItems adapter = new CustomListItems(Category.this,
                    yourArrayOfString);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {


                }
            });
```

customAdapter.class

```
public class CustomListItems extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Context context;
private String[] items;

public CustomListItems(Context context, String[] items,
        ) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_items_display);
    this.context = context;

    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.list_items_display, null, true);
    ImageView computerBook = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image_book);
    final ImageView shopIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image_shop);
    shopIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    computerBook.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

       @override 
       public void onClick(View view){
             shopIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
    });

    shopIcon.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

       @override 
       public void onClick(View view){
             //do shoping
       }
    });
    return rowView;

}

}
```